# Is the MailDefinition Class only for use with ASP?

Tags: c#, winforms, email, smtp

Is the [MailDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.maildefinition.aspx#Y1938) Class only for use with ASP? It seems to have everything I need, but apparently I need to add the SMTP server info in a Web.Config file. I want to use this class in a WinForms app. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Why you want to use MailDefinition class? You can use MailMessage class from System.Net right?

Comment: The MailDefinition allows the use of external HTML files and also enables you to edit the look and feel of the HTML template at any time, without having to rebuild and deploy your application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you should be able to use it from a WinForms app. You need to pass the SMTP host name to the System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient constructor. Something like this:

```
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

// namespace etc

private void SendEmail()
{
    string to = "to@somewhere.com,to2@somewhere.com";

    MailDefinition mailDefinition = new MailDefinition();
    mailDefinition.IsBodyHtml = false;

    string host = "smtpserver";  // Your SMTP server name.
    string from = "from@somewhere.com";
    int port = -1;               // Your SMTP port number. Defaults to 25.

    mailDefinition.From = from;
    mailDefinition.Subject = "Boring email";
    mailDefinition.CC = "cc@somwhere.com,cc2@somwhere.com";

    List<System.Net.Mail.Attachment> mailAttachments = new List<System.Net.Mail.Attachment>();
    // Add any attachments here

    using (MailMessage mailMessage = mailDefinition.CreateMailMessage(to, null, "Email body", new System.Web.UI.Control()))
    {
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(host);
        if (port != -1)
        {
            smtpClient.Port = port;
        }
        foreach (System.Net.Mail.Attachment mailAttachment in mailAttachments)
        {
            mailMessage.Attachments.Add(mailAttachment);
        }
        smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to add the ability to use credentials, but it works perfectly.